# Ray Multiprocessing benefits negated by increased function run-time

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, ray

I have a function which i pass 6 dictionaries, two strings and an integer.  In addition a list of 'element' ids is passed which the function loops through with a simple `for` statement.  The dictionaries contain results (float values) for a number of 'elements' where the keys are 'element' identifiers and the values are lists containing 6 float values.  The dictionaries vary in size but can contain as many as 1.5M key/value pairs.

The first part of the function interrogates the dictionaries, for results pertaining to the 'element' ID, and extracts them to Numpy arrays.  These are scaled up and some simple arithmetical calculations are undertaken. Note the two strings and the integer are used as additional identifiers and a starting id for the calculations. The function returns a dictionary containing the calculated results for each element.

The average run-time for the function (for each element) is approximately 1.2 seconds (0.2 for the initial extraction and 1.0 for the Numpy calculations.  The number of elements could be as much as 15,000 hence, requiring a not insignificant run-time.

As such, I have been investigating various multiprocessing modules to try and speed up the run-time (`Multiprocessing` / `Dask` / `joblib`), with, to be honest, not much success.  I have yet to get any of them to reduce the serial run-time.
I am now focussing on the `Ray` module, below is section of code calling up the function (which has been decorated using `@ray.remote`)

```
mech_arg = ray.put(mech_iru_out_ult_all)
wbap_arg = ray.put(wbap_iru_out_ult_all)
thermal_arg = ray.put(thermal_out_ult_reduced)
fp_arg = ray.put(fuel_pressure_out_ult_int)
ptol_arg = ray.put(ptol_out_ult_all)
pnl_supp_arg = ray.put(panel_support_out_ult_ret)
family_arg = ray.put("IRU")
condition_arg = ray.put("ULT")
start_id_arg = ray.put(70000001)

result = [calc_crit_prin_stress.remote(mech_arg,
                                       wbap_arg,
                                       thermal_arg,
                                       fp_arg,
                                       ptol_arg,
                                       pnl_supp_arg,
                                       family_arg,
                                       condition_arg,
                                       start_id_arg,
                                       elm) for elm in reqd_elements]

results = ray.get(result)
```

I am using `ray.put()` to create shared memory objects for the dictionaries/strings/integer.
The function is then called with `calc_crit_prin_stress.remote()` which includes a loop through of all element ids (`elm`) contained in the list ‘`reqd_elements`’.
Results are returned via `ray.get`.

Note: I am using a local Win10 / 32 Core / 128Gb Ram Desktop

The code executes ok, I can see all cores working in the task manager and i also get the results i expected, but I am only seeing a relatively small reduction in run-time.  The chart below shows the actual run-time for tests carried out, varying the number of CPU’s (for 50 elements).  The baseline serial `for` loop runtime was 59 seconds.  A similar time is found, using `Ray` with 4 cores.  Further increasing the cores to 8/16/32 however, shows much diminishing returns i.e. going from 4 to 32 cores only reduces the run-time by 15 seconds (approx. 25%).

[No of CPU's vs Actual Run-time(50 elements)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjqNM.jpg)

I then added some simple code to the function to output the time taken within the function to carry out the extraction and Numpy calculations (note: this does not significantly affect the overall run-time).  This showed the following

Time to extract:    0.206s (x4 cores)    0.649s (x32 cores)    factor of 3.15

Numpy calculations  1.129s (x4 cores)    7.777s (x32 cores)    factor of 6.89

Total    1.335s (x4 cores)    8.426s (x32 cores)    factor of 6.31

[No of CPU's vs function run-time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHnF.jpg)

Thus, although the number of cores has increased 8-fold, the increase in the actual runtime of the function has almost negated any benefit.
I understand that there are additional overheads involved in the set-up of the multiprocessing, but these times are within the function itself?  When we talk about multiprocessing here, is this limited to assigning a number of the loops to different cores only or is the execution of the function itself split across different cores leading to more overhead and increased run-time?  Is there something in my code that is causing this?

I would appreciate any guidance here.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd be able to be more exact if I could see actual working serial and parallel code. From what I see though it looks like you're likely assigning tasks one at a time through IPC. So when you have a lot of processes they spend a lot of time bottlenecking each other trying to grab information from a shared queue and then of course with many consumers they are likely processing these rays faster than the main process can assign new tasks.

Two easy approaches to cut down on this are to send multiple tasks at once like say 100 or 1000 depending on how many you have and how long they tend to take to calculate, or using shared memory (not as easy). Computers are very good at copying large amounts of data but very bad at efficiently controlling access to share data.

If you really wanted it to be fast you could do something with shared memory though that would require bitfiddling type operations that python isn't well suited for and serializing all the data items that you want to "send" to the consumers. I don't really use numpy often your data might already be suitable. Basically the plan would be to store all the data with spaces for answers (or a large chunk,) in shared memory which Python natively supports since 3.8. Then assign ranges of that table to different processes and have them signal when they are done through a Queue or something similar. You don't need to put everything into shared memory you can move batches into it and move them in and out after each batch is complete or even have different regions associated with different Processes. It's very similar to the use of larger batches through a queue but would be faster if you are transferring large amounts of data. It's a lot more complicated and more work so I'd do the batching approach though a Queue first.

I'm not all that familiar with the technique you're currently using with the decorator if you use a multiprocessing pool with a generator you can assign batch sizes and it will take care of everything for you.